# Force start GPS windows mobile 6.5

Tags: gps, compact-framework

I built a navigator and have a problem with the GPS, sometimes it takes forever to get a GPS-fix even though the device is outside with nothing blocking it. If I start TomTom the GPS gets a fix almost instantly on the same device. I can also get a fix faster if I restart the device.

Its like the GPS is in a sleep mode and has to be "poked" for it to start sending coordinates. Anyone knows anything about this and how to get it working faster in win CF c#?